# how can i get today in Room database queries

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, android-room

Hi I have a query where I order the list of products based on the product_end_date. I want to get only the list of products whose end date is greater than or equal to today, how can i do that in Room

here is my query

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM product_data_table ORDER BY product_end_date ASC")
    fun getAllProductsOrderByEndDate(): LiveData<List<Product>>
```

I tried this but did not work

```
   @Query("SELECT * FROM product_data_table WHERE product_end_date >= date('now') ORDER BY product_end_date ASC")
        fun getAllProductsOrderByEndDate(): LiveData<List<Product>>
```

Entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "product_data_table")
data class Product(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_id")
    var id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_name")
    var name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_catagory")
    var catagory: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_end_date")
    var end_date: Date
)
```

I am not sure how to use `todays date` in where clause

please suggest how to fix this

your help is much appreciated

Thanks
R

Comment: it will be nice if you also add your `Converter` for Date class

Comment: @i30mb1 i dont use any converter class as such

Comment: Then how is `end_date` transformed from an object to a column?

Comment: How do you think date('now') is supposed to work? It's nothing for Room queries. You can't compare the date in query. You should do some checks in the repository or viewmodel or whatever you use for receiving data.

Comment: @Viktor okay will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the `end_date` in Entity class as `Long` in Unix time

```
@Entity(tableName = "product_data_table")
data class Product(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_id")
    var id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_name")
    var name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_catagory")
    var catagory: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_end_date")
    var end_date: Long // Changed the type from Date to Long
)
```

When inserting the product pass `Date().time` for `end_date`

Now when querying, get the Unix time of today and pass it as a parameter for the query function. Something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM product_data_table WHERE product_end_date >= :endDate")
fun getAllProductsOrderByEndDate(endDate: Long): List<Product>
```